# How can I create a pop-up notification in Telegram bot?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I´m developing a telegram bot in c#. 
Using the class `TelegramBotClient` in `Telegram.Bot` library.

I want to create a pop-up notification after click on a `InlineKeyboardButton`.

Does anyone know how to do it?
Thank you very much.

I want to create something similar to this image:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have done in python:

```
bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "THIS IS AN ALERT", show_alert=True)
```

you have it in doc: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery

the parameter is show_alert

Comment: Thank you very much I will try to use de same method in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Just use method AnswerCallbackQueryAsync with optional "show alert" parameter in true, like this:

```
await botClient.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(e.CallbackQuery.Id, "Notification already enabled", true);
```